# Arch-rival / Arch-rivals

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Today while reading news I came across this line :

> India defeated Bangladesh to reach the champions trophy 2017 final where it will face **arch-rivals** Pakistan.

I doubted whether it will be arch-rival or arch-rivals so I googled for the word and found another sentence on oxford learners dictionaries website :

> a game between Rangers and their **arch-rivals** Celtic.

Merriam-Webster quoted this example

> In baseball, the Boston Red Sox and the New York Yankees are **archrivals.** ( Yes it was without hyphen)

For me the arch-rival**s** in third example seems fine as we are taking about two teams( two subjects are referred , indicated by **are** too that we are referring two subjects) which are arch rivals for each other. But the arch-rivals in first two example doesn't sounds all right, in first and second example we are talking about India's and Ranger's opponent (single subject) so shouldn't be *arch-rival* used there in place of *arch-rivals* ? Or it is because we are referring to collective noun( team) we have to use arch-rivals ? Or is it we always use *arch-rivals* everywhere ?

Another question, is it okay to use it without hyphen or its an error in Merriam-Webster ?

Comment: [Without the hyphen is fine](http://onelook.com/?w=archrival&ls=a). (In fact, I prefer that version.)

Answer (score 1):

In some dialects of English, teams, unless referred to by a plural name, are referred to in the singular (e.g. "Toronto is" but "the Blue Jays are").  In others, they are considered to be plural by default:

> Sunderland are one of the UK's most underrated football teams.
>
> Toronto is a very successful franchise in Major League Baseball's American League East.

I suspect this explains your difference.  Celtic would be considered plural in the UK, so are Rangers' arch-rivals, but the Boston Red Sox are the arch-rival of the New York Yankees.

Even here, it wouldn't be uncommon to consider a team to be "arch-rivals" even where teams are considered to be singular entities.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct but a little confusingly-worded. In some dialects, such as American English, collective nouns take singular verbs. In other dialects, such as British English, collective nouns may be considered singular or plural depending on context.

Comment: I suspected the same cause of the confusion, but here is what I don't get: if we're dealing with a variety of English that considers teams to be plural, why in the first sentence do we refer to India as "it" and then immediately switch to the plural, "arch-rivals"? Shouldn't it ether be "it will face arch-rival" *or* "they will face arch-rivals"?

Comment: @cjl750 that's the question for which I am too looking for the answer.